# Can't test JBoss-scheduled process outside JBoss

Tags: unit-testing, jboss, jakarta-mail, jboss5.x, junit4

I've got a JBoss Scheduled process (JBoss 5.0.0.GA, `org.jboss.varia.scheduler.Scheduler`) that's running in production.  It does its job.  It has no unit tests.  And I need to change it.

The job at hand is to connect to the company's Exchange server via IMAP, scan a specific folder for new messages, and do something to the messages that it finds.

So my first goal is to write some simple unit tests for it, and the first thing I want to do is just get a count of messages in the folder.  The code to do so, including printing out the count of messages in the folder, is already in the production code.  In creating my SSCCE for this post, I've essentially just removed the "and do something to the messages that it finds" part, along with a minor amount of obfuscation and simplification.

So now, the code:

```
package com.mycompany.utils;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.jboss.varia.scheduler.Schedulable;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;

public class BouncedEmailSimple implements Schedulable {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.mycompany.utils");

    @Override
    public void perform(Date pTimeOfCall, long pRemainingRepetitions) {
        String popHost = "192.168.1.55";
        String smtpHost = "192.168.1.55";
        String popUser = "username";
        String popPasswd = "password";
        Session session = null;
        Folder folder = null;
        Store store = null;

        try {
            Properties sysProperties = System.getProperties();
            sysProperties.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
            session = Session.getInstance(sysProperties, null);
            session.setDebug(false);

            logger.info("Started Bounce Email Simple process.");
            logger.info("user:" + popUser);
            logger.info("smtp:" + smtpHost);
            logger.info("pop:" + popHost);

            store = session.getStore("imap");
            store.connect(popHost, popUser, popPasswd);

            logger.info("store:" + store);

            folder = store.getDefaultFolder();

            logger.info("1");

            if (folder == null) {
                logger.error("No Default Mail Folder");
                throw new Exception("No Default Mail Folder");
            }

            logger.info("2");

            folder = folder.getFolder("Bounces");

            logger.info("3");

            if (folder == null) {
                logger.error("Bounce Mail folder not available");
                throw new Exception("Bounce Mail folder not available");
            }

            logger.info("4");

            folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

            logger.info("5");

            int totalMessages = folder.getMessageCount();

            logger.info("6");

            if (totalMessages == 0) {
                folder.close(false);
                store.close();
                return;
            }

            logger.info("7");
            logger.info("Messages to process = [" + totalMessages + "]");
            logger.info("8");

            System.out.println("Ended Bounce Email Simple processes.");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("BouncedEmailSimple Server Failure");
            logger.error("Error = [" + ex.getMessage() + "]");

            try {
                if (folder.isOpen()) {
                    folder.close(false);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex3) {
                ex3.printStackTrace();
            }
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (store.isConnected()) {
                    store.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex4) {
                ex4.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the unit test case:

```
package com.mycompany.utils;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Date;

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

public class BouncedEmailSimpleTest {
    @Test
    public void actualTest() {
        try {
            BouncedEmailSimple bes = new BouncedEmailSimple();
            bes.perform(new Date(), 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, the output is:

```
$ cat junit/TEST-com.mycompany.utils.BouncedEmailSimpleTest.txt 
Testsuite: com.mycompany.utils.BouncedEmailSimpleTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0.603 sec
------------- Standard Output ---------------
- Started Bounce Email Simple process.
- user:devsupport
- smtp:192.168.1.55
- pop:192.168.1.55
- store:imap://username@192.168.1.55
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
------------- ---------------- ---------------

Testcase: actualTest took 0.43 sec
    Caused an ERROR
com/sun/mail/util/MessageRemovedIOException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/MessageRemovedIOException
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.open(IMAPFolder.java:809)
    at com.mycompany.utils.BouncedEmailSimple.perform(Unknown Source)
    at com.mycompany.utils.BouncedEmailSimpleTest.actualTest(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mail.util.MessageRemovedIOException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I have `mail.jar` (version 1.3.something) on my classpath for my unit test, and this version of mail.jar does not contain the above class.  However, I have also downloaded JavaMail version 1.4.4, which does have the above class, and included 1.4.4 (and also excluded 1.3.something) on the classpath.  That produces a different error that I can't access right now (I'm no longer at my work computer where this post was started...)  However, it seems that there's something more fundamental at play here, or at least more specific to JBoss than I am positive of at this point.  The version of `mail.jar` on JBoss's classpath also doesn't contain the class above, so I'm more than thoroughly confused.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I came in to work this morning, I added back the JavaMail 1.4.4 jars to my classpath (and removed the 1.3.something jars), ran my test again, and it worked.  I'm writing this off to "something changed with the Exchange server overnight."

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at mail-1.3.jar and mail-1.4..4.jar and you are right about this class "MessageRemovedIOException". It is possible you are using latest version of imap.jar which is expecting this class. Looks like these 2 jars (and other pop3, smtp) go together with the implementation of Javamail.

Answer (score -1):

You should only have one version of mail.jar on your classpath.  As you've discovered, mixing and matching different versions doesn't work.

Comment: I explicitly stated that when I added the newer version of mail.jar to my classpath, I excluded the old one.

Comment: And you only have mail.jar, not any of the other JavaMail jar files?  Maybe there's another version of mail.jar being picked up from your environment somewhere?  Or possibly you have another jar file (e.g., javaee.jar) in your classpath that also contains the javax.mail.* classes?  The only way you're going to see the exception you're seeing is if you have a mix of JavaMail classes from different versions of JavaMail.